# How is Hottel's method of crossed strings valid?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Hottel's method calculates the view factor as $ F_{ij} = \frac{1}{2P_i} \times \text{(crossed - uncrossed lengths)} $ and similarly  $ F_{ji} = \frac{1}{2P_j} \times \text{(crossed - uncrossed lengths)} $. But the reciprocity law tells us that $ A_i F_{ij} = A_j F_{ji} $. How can both be true since in one case $ F_{ij} = \frac{P_j}{P_i} F_{ji} $ and in the other case $ F_{ij} = \frac{A_j}{A_i} F_{ji}  $ ?

Answer (score 0):

The Hotel's crossed-string method is used for two-dimensional geometry of infinite extent. The ratio between the both surfaces is then equal to the ratio between the 2 length.
Thus you will quickly understand that the both relation on the reciprocity of view factor are the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).